# Searching by key in mongodb/mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have Word Schema that contains a nested object as follows. If I wanted to search for words in "elementary_one_reading" with value xxx, I could simply do `db.words.find({"apperance.elementary_one_reading": xxx})`

However, I was wondering how I would do this in mongoose, assuming I wanted to pass in a variable for the key. In particular, I was hoping there would be a way to do something like below, but it does not work.

```
function(key, value) {
    Word.find({"appearance." + key: value}, function(err, results) {
    }

}


{ "word" : "岁", "_id" : ObjectId("1"), "appearance" : { "elementary_one_reading" : [ 1 ] }}
{ "word" : "女", "_id" : ObjectId("2"), "appearance" : { "elementary_one_reading" : [ 1 ] }}
{ "word" : "我", "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "appearance" : { "elementary_two_reading" : [ 1, 8 ] }}
{ "word" : "你", "_id" : ObjectId("4"), "appearance" : { "elementary_two_reading" : [ 1, 2 ] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that the easy way to solve this is via the use of queries. I could have easily done the following.

var field = 'appearance.elementary_one_reading';
Word.find().where(field, xxx).exec(callback);